# jquery functions are not working properly in multiple pages form

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress website, i am using a gravity form to complete one online application process with about 10 to 12 pages of form filling. Once a user fills out all the process and make it to payment method page (which is the last before page), he sees display of details about payment method he has chosen in previous page.

In the previous page, i had 3 options to choose like credit card, check, and money order. Now selecting credit card, works fine and displays its details in the next page. But for the other two - check and money order, anything among these are selected, the next page displays a black details area. I need to display of details according to the selection.

This is mainly because of the Jquery issue in displaying content.

In this page, there seems to be code like the below to display the contents and to stop them from displaying.

in **Plugins/gravity_forms/form_display.php**

```
  <div id='gform_page_{$form["id"]}_{$field["pageNumber"]}' class='gform_page{$custom_class}' {$style}>
                    <div class='gform_page_fields'>
  <ul class='gform_fields {$form['labelPlacement']}'>";
```

and li like

```
$style = !empty($form) && !IS_ADMIN && RGFormsModel::is_field_hidden($form, $field, $field_values) ? "style='display:none;'" : "";
```

$field_id = IS_ADMIN || empty($form) ? "field_$id" : "field_" . $form["id"] . "_$id";

```
return "<li id='$field_id' class='$css_class' $style>" . self::get_field_content($field, $value, $force_frontend_label, $form == null ? 0 : $form["id"]) . "</li>";
```

}

when form current page came then it show that fields other fields are display :none

I need to know how these process of display:block and none works accordingly in this situation. Which file is causing these all actions?

Here

i faced one more issue

for few id it does not show fields

so then for this i coded **Themes/function-application.php**

```
add_filter('gform_pre_render_'.$form_id, 'populate_checkbox',10);
function populate_checkbox($form)
{
```

in this ....
my code

```
         if($current_page==12){
                      require_once 'includes/application_form/payment.php';

                     ?>

                      <script type="text/javascript">
 alert('inside');
        jQuery("#field_1_212").css("display","block");
        jQuery("#field_1_129").css("display","block");
alert('after');
                        </script>

 <?php

 }
 ?>
```

here i find only first  alert inside worked fine .. and then jquery, alert after are all not worked.. 
so i need to know which file i need to modify ??

Thanks in advance..